# Priority queue as heap in C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree, heap, priority-queue

I know there are some similar questions like this, but sadly none of them really match my problem... So I'm supposed to create a priority queue as heap. We've been given some code snippets (rather pseudo code) to use, but if I print the tree, I won't get the correct numbers.

I'm currently just trying to insert random numbers into the queue and print them. A queue element is a custom class named Queue_elem. This is my insert      function:

```
void Queue::insert(Queue_elem item){

  this->container[number_elements] = item;
  if (this->number_elements > 0) this->upHeap();
  this->number_elements++;
}
```

number_elements is the counter for the size of the array (container). Here is my upHeap:

```
void Queue::upHeap(){
  for (int i = this->number_elements; i>=0; i = (i-1)/2) {
    int parent = (i-1)/2;
    if (this->container[i].getPriority() < this->container[parent].getPriority()) {
        swap(this->container[i], this->container[parent]);
    }
    break;
  }
```

}

And that's it. In my main I'm inserting random values and try to print them like this:

```
Queue que(11);

mt19937 rng;
rng.seed(random_device()());
uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dist6(1,50);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    Queue_elem tmp(dist6(rng));
    que.insert(tmp);
}

cout << que.container[0].getPriority() << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 5;i++) {

    cout << que.container[(2*i)+1].getPriority() << endl;
    cout << que.container[(2*i)+2].getPriority() << endl;
}
```

So I'm going through the tree child by child to print the array in the correct order, but it's always wrong...

I can also provide the whole project if necessary. Thanks a bunch in advance.

Edit: Queue_elem

```
class Queue_elem {
public:
    Queue_elem();
    Queue_elem(int prio);
    virtual ~Queue_elem();
    int getPriority();
    void setPriority(int prio);
    int getId();
private:
    int id;
    int priority;
```

};

Edit 2: The output is this:

```
1
18
29
26
37
30
44
46
48 
49
0
```

Comment: Why are you not using std::priority_queue?

Comment: Could you Post the `Queue_elem ` definition Class?

Comment: in your upHeap you have unconditional break. It seems it should be inside else. (if current_priority < parent_priority swap, otherwise break)

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd edited it :)

Comment: @Andrew Kashpur That still doesn't fix it. Oddly, it now has a better order, but there are still some numbers incorrect...

Comment: @Blade : could you show us the output ?

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd Yeah I put it at the end. Oddly, some numbers are correctly ordered, some are not. The 0 at the end is probably because the queue size is 11 but I only insert 10 numbers. Still, the other ones are partially wrong

Comment: @Blade What does "incorrect" mean here? It sounds like you are expecting your loop to give you all ten numbers in a sorted order. This structure gives you the correct value at the head of the queue. Instead take the head of the queue, print it, remove it, repeat

Comment: @Blade Jamn is wright it looks correct except that may be your output should be reversed (have to look how you inserted the elements)

Comment: @janm but if I loop through the array and use i*2+1 and +2 it should give me the children of i, so wouldn't it be the same or am I thinking in a wrong way?

Comment: @Blade You're looking at it the wrong way. I suggest you print out the array in index order, and then draw the tree from that array using a pencil and paper. And a minor point on your display code -- You don't display the root node, and you display one past the end!

Comment: have a look at [`std::push_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap) and the related functions

Comment: @janm Okay so I drew the binary tree and indeed there was one higher number before a lower one, because it was just in the node next to it's parent. So the heap condition is still fulfilled. Everything seems to work perfectly fine now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem. The output you show corresponds to this heap:

```
              1
      18             29
  26      37     30      44
46  48  49
```

That's a valid min-heap. Every child node is larger than its parent. Remember, in a heap, items aren't necessarily sorted.

The reason you're getting a 0 at the end is because you're trying to print the right child of a node that has no right child.